# Awaiting with null coalescing operator thrown exception

Tags: c#, async-await, null-coalescing-operator

I'm encountering some strange behavior.

When running this piece of code:

```
var foo = await actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal?.ToUserTokenAsync() ?? UserToken.UnidentifiedUser;
```

`Principal` is `null` at runtime and I get a null reference exception.

Why it's not just returning --> `UserToken.UnidentifiedUser`?

Comment: Which exception? There could be duplicates, but without exception I can't search for one.

Answer (score 20):

I believe this is a precedence problem. Your code is effectively:

```
var foo = (await actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal?.ToUserTokenAsync()) ??
          UserToken.UnidentifiedUser;
```

In other words, if *the result of awaiting* is null, then return `UserToken.UnidentifiedUser`. But you still try to do the awaiting - which means you might await something that's null, which fails.

What I suspect you want is:

```
var task = actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal?.ToUserTokenAsync()
    ?? Task.FromResult(UserToken.UnidentifiedUser);
var foo = await task;
```

Or avoid awaiting entirely when there's a null:

```
var task = actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal?.ToUserTokenAsync();
var foo = task != null ? await task : UserToken.UnidentifiedUser;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a null safe extension?

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> NullSafe<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        return task != default(Task) ? await task : default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Task<int> t = null;
int val = await (t).NullSafe();
```

And for the specific question try:

```
var foo = await (actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal?.ToUserTokenAsync())
    .NullSafe() ?? UserToken.UnidentifiedUser;
```

Comment: Nice, but the OP wants to have the `UserToken.UnidentifiedUser` as a fallback, not `default(T)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for pointing that out, I added a sample for the specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made somewhat more approachable by spinning the nullability on its head:

```cs
var principal = actionContext.RequestContext?.Principal;
var foo = principal != null ? await principal.ToUserTokenAsync() : UserToken.UnidentifiedUser;
```

As an added bonus - in my experience base objects that have an async method called from are more useful as a variable than Tasks they generate, although Jon's solution will work if you need the latter.

Thank god for ternaries.